# Gaussian prior favors values closest to zero?

Tags: normal-distribution, regression, naive-bayes

I am reading an article on Bayesian Logistic Regression, where they're using Logistic Regression, imposing a Gaussian prior (with mean = 0) on its parameters. They state that a Gaussian prior favors the values of the parameters to be near zero, but not exactly zero.

My question: if the mean is zero, how could it favor the parameters not being exactly zero?

The article I'm referring to is [this](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~madigan/PAPERS/techno.pdf) (Section 3).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that what is meant is simply that although the probability that the parameter is near $0$ is high, the probability that it is exactly $0$ is $0$.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHardy, but - why? They're talking about estimating parameters, I think that's considered to be a discrete distribution.

Comment: @Cheshie : A Gaussian distribution is _not_ a discrete distribution, regardless of whether it's used in interval estimation of parameters or for any other purpose and regardless of whether it's a prior or posterior distribution.

Comment: Oops... I guess you're right. Thanks so much! :)